# Theme from a classical ballet

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I heard this theme recently, I know I've already heard it before but I can't put my finger on it. Can anybody tell me where it's from? I reckon from a ballet?

I'm not so sure I'm allowed to post this here. If not, could you please tell me where I could go? Thank you!

[image: Score to music]

Comment: could be searched by melodyfinder.

Comment: It seems, that you are lacking a decent score typesetting software.

Comment: Related [question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/7068/1733).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overture to Rossini's The Thieving Magpie (La Gazza Ladra).